# When is a pushout diagram of rings with one surjective leg also a pullback diagram?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Suppose
\begin{align}
R      &&\xrightarrow{f} &&S\\
\downarrow& &&&\downarrow\\ 
R/I && \to&&T=((R/I)\otimes_RS)
\end{align}
is a pushout diagram of commutative unital rings. The surjective map $R\to R/I$ is the canonical one.

> What are conditions on $f$ such that the above diagram is also a pullback diagram, i.e. $R\cong R/I\times_TS$?

Comment: Injectivity is not sufficient. For a counter example take $R$ to be a domain, $I$ a non-zero ideal and $f$ the inclusion in the fraction field.

Comment: It is trivial that $I \cap \operatorname{ker} f =0$ is necessary. But you also need some condition to make sure that $IS$ is sufficiently "small". I guess that $IS \subset f(R)$ is also necessary.